# solve the differential equation $3xy'-2y^3=x^3y^{-2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

solve the differential equation  $3xy'-2y^3=x^3y^{-2}$

im trying to solve using bernoulis method

here the equation reduce into

$$\frac{y'}{y^{-2}} -2y^5=\frac{x^2}{2}$$

suppose if i choose $y^2=t \rightarrow 2y'=t'$

but i cant get proper differential equation to solve

can some give me hint what is tricky part here

thank you

Comment: May I suppose a typo in the equation ? I am skeptical about a closed form solution $y(x)$ or $x(y)$

Comment: This is not Bernouli equation, the Bernouli's equation has a linear part and a nonlinear plus the differential: $y'+p(x)y=q(x)y^n$